# Android sqlite (Database) Column missing error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity

I didn't understand ..why I am facing this error..

Here is my code:

```
package com.dswt.book;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookManager";
    private static final int DATABSE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_BOOKS = "books";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EDATA = "edata";
    final String TAG = "addBook";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABSE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BOOKS + "(" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_EDATA + " TEXT," + KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT " + ")";

        //Log.i(TAG, "error");

        db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOK_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_BOOKS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_EDATA, book.getName());
        values.put(KEY_NAME, "book.getEdata());

        db.insert(TABLE_BOOKS, null, values);
        db.close();// closing database connection

        Log.i(TAG, "see the value is adding");
    }

}
```

Here is my LOG CAT :

```
03-23 17:44:18.049: I/Database(6094): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table books has no column named edata
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094): Error inserting edata=satyam name=data display
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table books has no column named edata: , while compiling: INSERT INTO books(edata, name) VALUES(?, ?);
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1569)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at com.dswt.book.DatabaseHandler.addBook(DatabaseHandler.java:48)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at com.dswt.book.BookActivity.onCreate(BookActivity.java:21)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-23 17:44:18.049: E/Database(6094):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have changed the schema, you will need to increase `DATABSE_VERSION` (sic) so that the database can be upgraded, and the table will be recreated with the expected columns.

Comment: Yes...I solved the problem ..
I faced it first time..will just tell me database version dynamic value possible?